# How to prevent execution of a waf task if nothing changes from the last successful execution?

Tags: msbuild, waf

I have a waf task that is running a msbuild in order to build a project but I do want to run this only if last execution was not successful.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store in your `build.env.MS_SUCC = 1` and retrieve the value from the previous build (for the first time you naturally have to check if the dict item `MS_SUCC` exists)

Comment: Are this persistent between executions of waf? I am asking this because it is something quite normal to run a single task and I want to run the previous one only if last time it was executed it was a failure.

Comment: `env` is persistent between 2 timely distinct waf executions (except for the `distclean` target)

Comment: Thanks! next step is to make this transparendt for the tasks i'm writing... like saving the status for each task. :)

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you could simply use `build.env['foo-name-taks'] = 1/0` and do that in a loop (especially if your tasks already got defined name attributes)